# Loading a application inside another one

Tags: wpf, plugins, dll, user-interface, window

I would like my application WPF can load a ".exe" file and show it inside itself. I have my main WPF that checks a folder where it load plugins with MEF, but I only can load "dll" files without UI. So I found x plugins, I can load informations and in the same way I want to open a UI associate with the dll loaded.

I don't know if it's understandable what I want to do but if you have an idea that can help me, I take it.

Comment: Running the exe would involve creating a new process and starting it from your main application. Is that what you want to do? You can also have a look at [How to: Running multiple WPF applications in the same process using AppDomains](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2355)

Comment: You need to add a reference to the plugin.

Comment: What I want it's to incorporate something from a another project in mine without change my main application like I did with MEF for data. It's like if I want to show a toolbar in my browser without change it, just check if a toolbar is present in a folder and show it in a panel on my application.

Answer (score 1):

In a dll you can add UI elements.

Add for example a Window to your plugin project (project with dll output) and use the following code when you create an instance of your plugin in your main application:

```
Window win = new Window();

win.Show();
```